# Disappearing/reappearing text glitch when addition transition on Chrome

Tags: html, css

Previously I had a static card component (.product) which was working perfectly. However, I wanted to add functionality to make the image on the card grow when the user hovers over the parent card element, as you can see here:

```css
.product {
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 80px;
  width: 100%;
  max-height: 100vh;
  min-width: 100px;
  background-color: white;
  z-index: 1;
  position: relative;
}

.product > img {
  user-select: none;
  max-height: 200px;
  width: 100%;
  object-fit: contain;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  transition: 0.3s; /*Added line*/
}

.product:hover > img {
  transform: scale(1.1); /*Added line*/
}
```

Here is the HTML of the card (I'm using React):

```html
    <div className="product">
      <div className="product__header">
        <div className="product__info">
          <h2> {product.title} </h2>
          <p className="product__price">
            <small> $ </small>
            <strong> {product.price} </strong>
          </p>
          <div className="product__rating">{ratingOutput()}</div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <img src={product.image} alt="" />
      <div className="product__ingredients">
        <p> Ingredients: {product.ingredients}</p>
      </div>
      <button onClick={addToBasket} style={{ backgroundColor: buttonColor() }}>
        {" "}
        Add to Order{" "}
      </button>
    </div>
```

But after I added the two CSS lines, it would occasionally cause the other text components that are on the card to disappear when hovering on Chrome. The glitchy text will then randomly appear and disappear again when the mouse moves.

Key Details

- I'm experiencing this problem on Chrome (V96.0.4664.93) and have not been able to replicate it using Firefox (V95.0) or Edge (V96.0.1054.53)
- It happens on my monitor which is 1900px wide and the glitch seems to go away when I narrow the window to less than 1700px
- Also haven't been able to replicate it with just the transform property alone, so it appears to be from the addition of the transition property

The first two images below are examples of the text being distorted/disappearing as a result of hovering and the last image is what it looks like normally.

[image: Example 1 of disappearing/glitchy text]

[image: Example 2 of disappearing/glitchy text]

[image: How it looks normally without hovering]

Comment: Please provide minimal example of card with HTML and CSS for us to inspect. Does it appears on all browsers and different versions of them?

Comment: Thank you for the comment, I've made sure to add those details to my question. Essentially it seems to be only appearing on Chrome (not Firefox or Edge) and when the window size is above around 1700px, though it's difficult to reproduce in general.

Comment: Because for me it seems like browser issue, not code

Comment: You added code to the question, but not in the form of a demo. Please use the editor to do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added `-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;` to .product and that seemed to solve the issue.